# Shortcut to MySql on Mac OS X?

Tags: mysql, macos, path

I am trying to add a path so I don't have to keep typing `usr/local/mysql/bin` every time I want to start Mysql. I found instructions [here](http://www.comentum.com/mysql-administration.html) that say:

Edit the file /etc/profile and update the path by adding:
`usr/local/mysql/bin/`, for example:
`PATH="/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin"`

Problems:
1. There is no existing line in my profile file that says 'path'. This is what it currently says in profile:
    # System-wide .profile for sh(1)

```
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval '/usr/libexec/path_helper -s'
fi
if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
    [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

2. I really have no idea what I'm doing on a mac (yet). What do I add/change to the above file so mysql is easier to access?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It depends on whether or not you want all user accounts to have access to MySQL, or just you.

For everyone, edit /etc/profile as instructed and add the following to the end:
`export PATH=$PATH:usr/local/mysql/bin`

For just you (ALSO, this is safest so you don't accidentally mess up any system variables!):

Get a terminal session: Launch Terminal if it's not already running.

Make sure you're in your home directory:
`CD ~`

See if .bash_profile exists:
`ls -al .b*`

If it does, open it with your favorite text editor. If it doesn't, launch your favorite text editor and Save as... `.bash_profile` in your home folder.

Add this line to .bash_profile and Save:
`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin`

Then close Terminal and open again for the change to take effect.

Hope this works out for you.

Comment: Hi Matt, I added the line to bash_profile but after restarting Terminal, it isn't working. I still have to type in the full `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p`. .bash_profile now looks like this: `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
export PATH=$PATH:usr/local/mysql/bin.`

Comment: Hm. Try this. In Terminal type "echo $PATH" to make sure "/usr/local/mysql/bin" is actually in the path. Also, at the end of the export line you added, does it actually say "export PATH=$PATH:usr/local/mysql/bin." exactly? Because as quoted in your response there's a period after the /bin, and you don't want that there. "/bin." != "/bin"

Comment: I just caught a mistake in what I told you to add to .bash_profile. I left out the slash in front of the path. GO into .bash_profile and change the line to: export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin